# Knockout foreach only display if property = value?

Tags: knockout.js

I originally had something like the following:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: objects">
    <span data-bind="if: object.type() === 'menuItem'>
       ...
    </span>
</span>
```

This technically worked, but it actually created a DOM element for EVERY object, regardless of type, but the matching ones were the only ones "populated".  It left slight gaps in the UI.

I switched to using a virtual element, which works much better, but still shows up in the DOM as

```
<!-- ko if: object.type() === 'menuItem'>
<!-- /ko -->
```

for all the nonmatching elements.

Is there a way to embed the if statement in the original foreach or would it be better to do this logic in the viewmodel somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot embed an `if` in the same element as a `foreach` because they are trying to control the same descendant binding, which is the error that Knockout will give you when you try.

http://jsfiddle.net/h92LY/

The use of a containerless binding is 100% the correct direction to go.  Another option is using a computed where the condition is inside of it, but that is taking presentation logic into the view model -

view model -

```
var showingObjects= ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(objects(), function(object) {
        return object.type() === 'menuItem';
    });
});
```

view -

```
<span data-bind="foreach: showingObjects">
       ...
</span>
```

Comment: So if I have a thousand objects and 5 of them are menuFolders I shouldn't worry about the 995 ko comments in the dom?  I'm not being sarcastic, seriously wanting to confirm.

Comment: If you want the 995 objects that were hidden to be properly data bound and show if the value you are testing against changes, then correct, you need to leave the 995 comments there or go with a computed like mentioned.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have presentation logic in the view model. That's why it's a **view** model and not just a **model**.

Comment: The answer was still clear in that there are at least two answers that are applicable in this situation and it is up to the developer to decide which is best for their app